# How do I display correct data from mySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am trying to query a database and display the results. The query is based on information from an html form. However, when I enter a name such as john in the form, for which the table has 2 entries with that name, I get 0 results. I don't know what the problem is.

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="cust_details_search.php" method="post">         
Name :
<input type="text" name="name_search" id="name_search" >
Email :
<input type="email" name="email_search" id ="email_search" >

Phone no. :

 <input type="phone" name="phone_search" id="phone_search" >


Address :
<input type="text" name="address_search" id="address_search" >

City :
<input type="text" name="city_search" id="city_search" >

State :
<input type="text" name="state_search" id="state_search" >
<br> <br>
Country :
<input type="text" name="country_search" id="country_search">

Product Enquired for :
<input type="text" name="prod_search" id="prod_search">  

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

And the php file:

```
 <?php 
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";

//create connection
$dbconn = new mysqli($server, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

 $name_search = $_POST['name_search'];
 $email_search = $_POST['email_search'];
 $phone_search = $_POST['phone_search'];
 $address_search = $_POST['address_search'];
 $city_search = $_POST['city_search'];
 $state_search = $_POST['state_search'];
 $country_search = $_POST['country_search'];
 $prod_search = $_POST['prod_search'];

$run_query = mysqli_query($dbconn, 
            "SELECT * 
            FROM CustomerDetails 
            WHERE (Name  LIKE '%.$name_search.%') 
            OR (`Phone no.` LIKE '%.$phone_search.%') 
            OR (`Address` LIKE '%.$address_search.%') 
            OR (`City` LIKE '%.$city_search.%') 
            OR (`State` LIKE '%.$state_search.%') 
            OR (`Country` LIKE '%.$country_search.%') 
            OR (`Product Enq. For` LIKE '%.$prod_search.%') 
            OR (`Email` LIKE '%.$email_search.%')");

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Resutls</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: rgb(131,41,54);
}
h1 { color:#FFFFFF
        }
h2 {  color:#FFFFFF
        }
p {  color:#FFFFFF
        } 

</style>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2> Customer Details </h2>
 <table style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone no. </th>
    <th>Address </th>
    <th>City </th>
    <th>State </th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Product Enquired for </th>
    <th>Follow up details </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
 ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $result['Name'] ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $result['Email'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['Phone no.'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['Address'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['City'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['State'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['Country'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['Product Enq. For'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['Follow Up'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the dots for? `LIKE '%.$name_search.%')` remove the dots, like so: `LIKE '%$name_search%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the PHP concatenator `.` but you dont need to in a double quoted string. `$variables` are automatically expanded in a double quoted string so try

```
$run_query = mysqli_query($dbconn, 
            "SELECT * 
            FROM CustomerDetails 
            WHERE (Name  LIKE '%$name_search%') 
            OR (`Phone no` LIKE '%$phone_search%') 
            OR (`Address` LIKE '%$address_search%') 
            OR (`City` LIKE '%$city_search%') 
            OR (`State` LIKE '%$state_search%') 
            OR (`Country` LIKE '%$country_search%') 
            OR (`Product Enq For` LIKE '%$prod_search%') 
            OR (`Email` LIKE '%$email_search%')");
```

ALso some of your column names had a `.` in them? I assume these column names do not actually contain dots. However if the do, I suggest you remove them by editing your schema.

> Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: +1. Also worth mentioning that although he doesn't need to do that in a double quoted string, it would still work if he did it correctly: `"...LIKE '%".$name_search."%')..." `

Comment: @HtmHell In my opinion that just makes the string 10x more complicated and when the query gets complicated almost impossible to debug

Comment: Sure, but my point is that he should understand that a dot inside a string will not make a concatenation, only if he first add another quote/double quote